# Seam - Multiple Persistence Units

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, seam, persistence-unit

Does Seam support multiple persistence units in its configuration?  Also, when would you want to have or need multiple persistence units?

I am working on a generic component and right now, it only supports a single persistence unit which makes sense to me as I have never used more than 1 persistence unit per web application.  So, I am having difficulty seeing where you would use more than a single persistence unit.

Thanks,

Walter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Seam support multiple persistence units in its configuration?

I don't see why it wouldn't. Configure several persistence units and get them injected by name:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="UNITNAME")
private EntityManager em;
```

> Also, when would you want to have or need multiple persistence units?

If you need to access multiples datasources.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking more along the lines of having multiple identity managers.  It looks like you can only have 1 jpa identity store.  You could probably shoehorn more in there, but I don't believe that part was designed for more than one much like configuring an email sender only supports 1 address.

Comment: I take that back, you can have more than 1, but it gets ugly fast.

Answer (score 0):

It's very well possible to have multiple persistence units in JPA and in JPA with Seam. In Seam it's very easy. Just create more than one `<persistence-unit name="myapp" />` elements in your persistence.xml and configure an EntityManagerFactory for each unit, and optionally an EntityManager for each EntityManagerFactory. You can then simply inject any EntityManager in the standard way:

```
@In
EntityManager entityManagerOne;
```

where your EntityManager is named `entityManagerOne` (and the other `entityManagerTwo`).

The most important reason to have multiple persistence units is the requirement to work with multiple database systems. This is not related to a data source, but the issue is simply to define a scope for your entity mappings.

Another reason is that you choose a transaction strategy (global (JTA) or local (resource-local)) per persitence unit. So, if you need to work with multiple transaction strategies you can create 2 persistence units for the same database.